# Could not load type 'System.Dynamic.IInvokeOnGetBinder'

Tags: c#, exception, c#-3.0

I have a .Net Core 3.1 WPF app. It needs to connect to a service and pull/push data to that service. The app executable works without any error message. However, when I publish the Self Contained app and make it a single exe file, It is not able to connect to the service and throws an exception with the following message.

> Could not load type 'System.Dynamic.IInvokeOnGetBinder' from assembly netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral

What may cause this exception?

Answer (score 0):

This must be a bug on the Microsoft side. I went ahead and unchecked the `Trim unused assemblies` and the app starts working. Although this outputted a bigger executable file, Trimming seems to be removing too much if enabled.

[image]